# Is VeriSign G5 Root Certificate free?

Tags: ssl-certificate, verisign

I want to know if Verisign G5 Root Certificate is free to use . i have commercial website and want to install wildcard certificate to it because it has paypal integration. 
I found a link to download the certificate.

https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5624

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verisign G5 Root Certificate is intended for trust purposes only. You cannot install it on web site to utilize SSL. This is because SSL requires private key, while the private key of VeriSign is held by VeriSign privately. You have to purchase SSL certificate from commercial CA provider.

Comment: But i received email from paypal to install this G5 Root and i am confused if i have to update my windows server or install SSL certificate on Website to fulfill the condition. please see this URL: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: What they suggest is to install VeriSign root certificate in the trust store (Local Machine\Trusted Root CAs). It has nothing to do with your web server.

Comment: many thanks ! is there any guidelines to install it on local machine ?

Comment: is this Root certificate free to install on trust store ?